# Issue with error "scrollTheView" undeclared

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm working through a tutorial on creating apps. I followed along and have everything written EXACTLY as the tutorial. However when I hit the build I get a few errors.
Below is a snippet of the code of a method I have in the implementation file. I'm getting an error ....(scrollTheView' undeclared)... also i have another error stacked with it that is (expected ';' before ':' token).....

Below this method I will include my entire Header file, which i've declared the method "scrollTheView" so i dont understand where i went wrong. The tutorial was using SDK iPhone OS 2.2.1, I however am using SDK iphone 4.3, could this be the actual cause for this problem? I've edited the post to include the entire implementation file. At the end of the code i also get a error 'expected declaration or statement at end of input' and another saying '@end' missing in implementation context' thanks for all those who viewed and are tryiing to help me.
 thank you scott for helping me out with that missing bracket.. now i have a notice that pops up even tho  it compiles .. " UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated notice"  anyone know what that means? as it stil compiles, should i be worried? it appears on the line of "NSValue* aValue..... "line under the method 'keyboardWillShow'

```
 #import "ReturnToMeViewController.h"  
 #import "ReturnToMeAppDelegate.h"

@implementation ReturnToMeViewController

@synthesize textField;  
@synthesize label;  
@synthesize callNumber;  

-(void)viewDidLoad {  
    textField.clearButtonMode =
    UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
}




-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)  
                        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                        object:self.view.window];  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
            name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];  
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];  
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *)notif {

    NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];  

    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];  
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue] .size;  
    float bottomPoint = (textField.frame.origin.y+textField.frame.size.height+10);  
    scrollAmount = keyboardSize.height - (self.view.frame.size.height- bottomPoint);  

    if (scrollAmount >0) {
        moveViewUp =YES;   
        [self scrollTheView:YES]; 
    }
    else {
        moveViewUp =NO;  

    }



-**(void) scrollTheView:(BOOL) movedUp {**

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        if (movedUp) {
            rect.origin.y -= scrollAmount;
        }
        else {
            rect.origin.y += scrollAmount;
        }
        self.view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

-(void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {  
        if ( textField.editing) {  
            [textField resignFirstResponder];  
            [self updateCallNumber];  
            if (moveViewUp) [self scrollTheView:NO];  
        }
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];  
    }



-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


-(void)dealloc {  
    [textField release];  
    [label release];   
    [callNumber release]; 
    [super dealloc];  
}

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)theTextField {  

        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];   
        if (moveViewUp) [self scrollTheView:NO];  
        [self updateCallNumber]; 

        return YES;  
    }

-(void)updateCallNumber {    
        self.callNumber = textField.text;  
        label.text = self.callNumber;  
    }  

@end


###ReturnToMeViewController.m

    #import <  UIKit/UIKit.h >  

    @interface ReturnToMeViewController : UIViewController
        < UITextFieldDelegate > {  
        IBOutlet UITextField *textField;  
        IBOutlet UILabel *label;  
        BOOL    moveViewUp;  
        CGFloat  scrollAmount;  
        NSString  *callNumber;  

    }  

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField;  
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;  
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *callNumber;  

    - (void)scrollTheView:(BOOL) movedUp;  
    - (void)updateCallNumber;  

    **@end**
```

Comment: Where are you getting the build errors? Double clicking the errors in the error box usually gets you to the line that it's confused about.

Comment: From where and how you are calling the scrollTheView: method?

Comment: sorry im trying to reformat it so its easier to see.. i see how to create line breaks but i dont see how some of my methods are put in a blue box and some aren't

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are missing a close bracket "}" or a semicolon ";" somewhere before your scrollTheView function.

Answer (score 0):

There could well be an error *before* you declare scrollTheView, meaning it can't detect scrollTheView. Take a look or post more code here.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket at the end of your `keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif` method.

```
if (scrollAmount >0) {
    moveViewUp =YES;
    [self scrollTheView:YES];
}
else {
    moveViewUp =NO;
} // This is where the missing bracket should be
}
```

There need to be two closing brackets – one for the `if` statement and one for the method – but there's only one.

Comment: holy crap! thank you Scott!! fastest reply i've seen and not only that but solved it..  it compiles .. however i also have a " UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated notice"  anyone know what that means? as it stil compiles, should i be worried?